# Install Appexchange app in only one Business Unit

Tags: appexchange, connected-apps, marketing-cloud

I would like to install a specific app from the AppExchange in a specific business unit.

Could you please indicate the steps to install it on only one child BU?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to install in just one BU, but you can control where it's visible:

1. Go to the BU where you want to install the app and click on the AppExchange link from the menu
2. The app installation will open in SETUP > INSTALLED PACKAGES
3. When the app is installed, go to the Licenses tab:

[image]

4. Check all the boxes for users who should have access to the app in the child BU and click on Save
5. In other BUs, where no one should have access, make sure that all users are unchecked. Save.

> NOTE: Whoever has access to Setup > Installed Packages, will have the
>   ability to change the visibility settings form any BU

Comment: There's more details contained in this article.Manage Licensing for Installed Packages
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/license-installed-packages.htm